# What % and & in this code?

Tags: php

I wonder what % and & in the following PHP code do.

```
$num_one = rand() % 10;
$num_two = rand() & 10;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

% is modulo, so

```
$num_one = rand() % 10
```

gives you a number between in [0..10), while & means bitwise and, such that

```
$num_one = rand() & 10
```

gives you a random number with only a combination of the bits 2 and 4 set, like in [2,8,10].

Answer (score 3):

% is [modulus](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) (remainder after division).

& is [bitwise and](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

Answer (score 1):

`&` is the [bitwise AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) operator. `%` is the modulus (remainder of `rand() / 10` in this case).

Answer (score 1):

& is a bitwise operator. [click me](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)

% is an arithmetic operator. [click me](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)